# How can I refresh or reload a WKwebview when selecting tabs

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, tabbed

I have a tabbed app which loads separate internal file WKwebviews. I now need to have the WKwebview refresh when a tab is selected.

I think I need to add the required code in the viewWillAppear, but on trying to have some code on this method nothing works.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can achieve this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "jsHandler")
        let bundleURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.absoluteURL
        let html = bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("main/index.html") //Loads internal HTML files
        webView.loadFileURL(html, allowingReadAccessTo:bundleURL)
        webView!.uiDelegate = self
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true //Allows 'safari' style gestures swipe back etc
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //Nothing
    }
```

Update:
To resolve this, I added the above code into the `viewDidAppear` method rather than the `viewDidLoad`. This has resolved the problem.
The JS message handler still needs to be in the `viewDidLoad`.

Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "jsHandler")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "jsHandler")
        let bundleURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.absoluteURL
        let html = bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("index.html") //Loads internal HTML files
        webView.loadFileURL(html, allowingReadAccessTo:bundleURL)
        webView!.uiDelegate = self
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true //Allows 'safari' style gestures swipe back etc
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this on each tab action:

```
func reloadTabAction() {
    if let url = webView.url {
        webView.reload()
    } else {
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: originalURL))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have 2 questions on this. 1. Where do I add this function as I do not have any tab actions. 2. Is there an advantage to having an if statement here? thanks

Comment: 1. If you do not have action but on selecting the tabs if `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` fires you can add my code into `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` 2. some times web page fail to load offline, then `webView.url` be `nil`, in such case you should check if url is present then reload your webView

Answer (score 1):

We have reload property for WKWebView. So you can directly call the method.
You can call the method while tapped the tabView
Try the below code,

```
webView.reload()
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This didn't work in the viewWillAppear method, am I putting it in the wrong place?